# Open iTerm2 SSH session in new window instead of new tab

Tags: macos, ssh, iterm

Now that I figured out how to [set iTerm2 as the ssh:// URL handler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28938), I'd like iTerm2 to respond to an ssh URL by opening a new window instead of opening a new tab in an existing window. Is this possible?

Comment: You can drag any tab out of an iTerm 2 window to create a new window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious about the same problem. After [reviewing the source code](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/source/checkout), I found in iTerm2 v1.0.0.20111020 is hard-coded to open a new session as a tab if a session already exists, when it receives nearly any "launch this URL with a handler" command.

My Xcode and Objective-C skills are still rather weak, but if you want to give it a shot I believe the problem is related to the source file **iTermController.m**. On lines 789 to 870 the `launchBookmark:withURL` method has the following code:

```
// Where do we execute this command?
BOOL toggle = NO;
if (theTerm == nil) {
    [iTermController switchToSpaceInBookmark:aDict];
    term = [[[PseudoTerminal alloc] initWithSmartLayout:YES
                                             windowType:[aDict objectForKey:KEY_WINDOW_TYPE] ? [[aDict objectForKey:KEY_WINDOW_TYPE] intValue] : WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
                                                 screen:[aDict objectForKey:KEY_SCREEN] ? [[aDict objectForKey:KEY_SCREEN] intValue] : -1] autorelease];
    [self addInTerminals: term];
    toggle = [term windowType] == WINDOW_TYPE_FULL_SCREEN;
} else {
    term = theTerm;
}

id result = [term addNewSession: aDict withURL: url];
```

I suspect that when `theTerm == nil`, `addNewSession` works as expected by launching a new window, since one is currently not running. Perhaps you can modify the code to force the first block to always run, regardless of `theTerm`'s contents.

I hope this helps!! .. It may be worth [filing a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/entry) or [contacting the author](http://www.twitter.com/!#/gnachman) if you're still having problems.

Comment: Submitted a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=1567

Comment: +1 on Google Code. I would purpose that there be an option to disable tabs entirely, as I personally never use them. However this may be overkill as the only time I've ever encountered a "forced tab" is by this use-case. So if upstream can fix this specific bug I'll be happy too :)

Comment: I can't believe this was logged in 2011 but it's still happening now! I can't find an option in iterm to disable the new tab behaviour. Am I missing something? Sorry for resurrecting such an old post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of iTerm2, under **Preferences > Advanced > Windows** there's this option:

```
Open files in new windows, not new tabs
```

Set this to **Yes** to have scripts open in a new window.