# How to change URL handler for firefox?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ssh, url

Basically I want firefox to open URLs starting with "ssh://whoever@wherever" using iterm2.

Unfortunately I didn't pay attention - the first time I tried this, Mac Os suggested to use *Terminal*, and stupid me also clicked the checkbox to remember that setting. Now I can't figure how to undo/change that decision.

I have seen this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/set-iterm2-as-the-ssh-url-handler) - but unfortunately that one is 7 years old and seems to be outdated (my preferences->profile window doesn't look at all like the one shown in the existing question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you need to delete/change the association within Firefox.

1. Go into Firefox Preferences (hamburger menu in upper right hand corner of window or press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Scroll down to Applications.  You can either scroll through or search for the association you wish to modify

   [image]
3. Delete the association; the next time you click on the link it will ask you what you want to do.  Or... change the association to the application you wish to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

For another alternative with many additional functions...

While it's been around for quite some time, nonetheless it still works.

Give [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), by Rubicode, a try.

[image]

Note: I have no affiliation with the developer Rubicode, just enjoy using this free utility.